# Issue in migration of Vee Validate from 2.2 to 3.X

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I was using vee-validate v2.2.0 for validation in my project.Now i am migrating to Version 3.0.
Is there a migration document available..?
I was able to complete all front end level validation by using ValidationProvider and It is working fine.
I am facing issues with Validation of all fields before submit/save.
Earlier I was doing like
    `this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {`
I was going through the documentation and I read that same we can do by using ValidationObserver.
I have added sample code. I want to get all the errors inside the validate function
https://jsfiddle.net/r4m3xh6c/23/

I was following this working example https://jsfiddle.net/logaretm/p5uetgcv/15/
but here veevalidate version is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the scoped data of `ValidationObserver` like `valid` to see if the all the fields inside the `ValidationObserver` component are valid.

You can use the `passes` callback, which is run after the form converts to a valid form.
Documentation for the same:
https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/validation-observer.html#scoped-slot-data

Your updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/5xtcamp8/

Let me know if that helps. If you can describe what you want to achieve that'd be better, maybe I can give the complete solution or at least guide you in that direction.

Comment: We are doing the upgrade  because the older version have many performance issues and I see a big improvement after upgrading to new version.I got help from the vee-validate team on git. This is working  example  of same.https://jsfiddle.net/logaretm/5ojnu2be/1/

Comment: Their documentation has improved in the past few days, do check it out again